# Unable to understand the behavior of following program ( Using java collection)

Tags: java, list, collections, set

I have following program in which I am adding few number to set and list and then removing them, Could some one please explain why Set and list have different behavior.

```
public class SetList {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=-3;i<3;i++){
        set.add(i);
        list.add(i);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        set.remove(i);
        list.remove(i);
    }
    System.out.println(set+"            "+list);
}
```

}

and output is

```
[-3, -2, -1]            [-2, 0, 2]
```

I am able to understand the behavior of Set but unable to understand the behavior of List output. All help really appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set and List are different types of [collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/index.html). Set is an associative collection, thus `Set.remove(i)` will remove the element having the *value* of `i`. While List is an indexed collection, so `List.remove(i)` removes the element at the `i`th *position* in the list.

So after removing the elements 0 to 3 from a Set containing elements of -3 ... 3, your Set will predictably contain the values -3 to -1.

With the List, the outcome of the same sequence of removals may be a bit more surprising, but it is actually logical. Originally your list contains:

```
Index  0  1  2  3  4  5  6
Value -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3
```

`list.remove(0)` removes the element at index 0, resulting in

```
Index  0  1  2  3  4  5
Value -2 -1  0  1  2  3
```

Notice that all elements after the (removed) first have shifted one position forward! Thus, when `list.remove(1)` removes the element at index 1, it "hops over" the element -2. The result is

```
Index  0  1  2  3  4
Value -2  0  1  2  3
```

Similarly the next operation, `list.remove(2)` "hops over" the element 0, resulting in

```
Index  0  1  2  3
Value -2  0  2  3
```

And last, `list.remove(3)` removes the last element, giving the end result:

```
Index  0  1  2
Value -2  0  2
```

Comment: +1 Beside the Set does not allow the duplicated elements to be added on adding them.

Comment: Thanks Peter, Forgive my ignorance but I can't get it, for me ( element at index 0 is -3, index 1 contain -2 and index 2 contain -1 ) sorry if I am doing anything wrong but I am really confused. So it should print [0 1 2 ]

Comment: Awesome ... Super Like :) :) Thank you so much                                       You saved me

Answer (score 0):

When calling Set.remove(int) java will auto-box your parameter to an Integer, but there exists a List.remove(int) which removes the values by their index.